# Add event by clicking button design of axml in monodroid?

Tags: xamarin.android

Is it possible to add button click event by clicking design of axml?
if yes then how? if no how can i add by other way?
i am trying to make my first application using visual studio 2010.

code sample

```
public class Activity1 : Activity
{
     string dbPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "tdsl_validation.sqlite");



        private Button login_button;
        private EditText  user;
        private EditText passs;






    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        var ss=dbPath;

         base.OnCreate(bundle);
         user = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.editText1);
         passs = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.editText3);
         login_button = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.button1);
         login_button.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
         SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);


    }


    private  bool validate_user(string username, string password)
    {
        bool i;
        i = true;
        string str;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string dbPath1 = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "tdsl_validation.sqlite");

        SqliteConnection con = new SqliteConnection("Data Source="+ dbPath1);
        str = "select pass from user_detail where user_name='" + username + "' and pass='" + password + "'";
        SqliteCommand cmd = new SqliteCommand(str, con);
        SqliteDataAdapter da = new SqliteDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);


        if (dt != null)
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                i = true;

            }
            else
            {
                i = false;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            i = false;
        } 

        return i;

    }





    void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool i;
         user = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.editText1);
         passs = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.editText3);
         i = validate_user(user.Text, passs.Text);

         i = validate_user(user.Text, passs.Text);
         if (i == true)
         {

         }
         else
         {
             Toast.MakeText(this, "Invalid Username or Password", ToastLength.Short).Show();
         }



        // stuff here
    }








}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default project template for a new Mono for Android application includes an example of how to handle a button's click event. I don't believe there's any way in the current designer to wire this up by hand. Using the example from the default template, let's say the button in your layout, Main.axml, has an ID of "MyButton" (@+id/MyButton). In your activity, you would need to do the following:

First, declare that Main.axml should be used as the layout for the activity:

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
```

Once you declare the layout, you can get references to elements within the layout. This lets you get a reference to the button:

```
Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
```

Once you have that, you can hook into the Click event on that button in order to handle when the button is clicked:

```
button.Click += delegate { 
    // handle the click event here
};
```

Alternatively, if you want to use a separate method for the click handler rather than defining it inline, you can do something like this:

```
button.Click += ButtonClicked;

private void ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    // handle button click here
}
```

**Edit (based on comments and updated question)**

As mentioned before, SetContentView() needs to be called *before* you can call FindViewById(). SetContentView() tells Android which layout you want to use for the activity, so until you do that, it would have no idea where to find your UI elements. Move the SetContentView() call above the FindViewById() calls, and also make sure that the layout you want is Main.axml. If it has a different name, you need to specify the correct name in the call to SetContentView().

I would also suggest greatly simplifying your code to start off with, just to narrow down where problems could potentially arise from. Currently your button click is going to start trying to access the database and do other things, but I'd suggest just getting your click handler working properly before taking that step.

Comment: Unhandled Exception:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   i have used the  login_button = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.button1);

             login_button.Click += button1_Click;

Comment: Did you set call SetContentView() using the layout that contains button1? That needs to happen before you can call FindViewById()

Comment: user = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.editText1);
             passs = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.editText3);
             login_button = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.button1);
             SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
             login_button.Click += button1_Click;   the error message comes while executing the last line

Comment: Why are you calling SetContentView() again before attaching the click handler? I'm assuming you're also calling it before the other FindViewById() calls, or else they wouldn't work either. If I had to guess, and it's a guess because I don't have many details here, I'd say that your layout isn't called Main, and you're losing a reference to the UI element by resetting the layout. Please provide more details/code (ideally not in comments so they're readable) if you're still having problems.

Comment: hi , i have added sodes in question

Comment: i have added SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main); below          base.OnCreate(bundle); and it runs. thank you